# Download cygwin packages from a predefined list (on Windows 7)

Tags: automation, cygwin, packages

I have a very long list of cygwin packages that I need to download (for various reasons I cannot install directly from the internet, instead I need to download the cygwin packages for later installation). Is there any way of doing this by providing a list of packages to some automated procedure rather than selecting each package by clicking in the gui? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/cyg-get) package manager uses [Cyg-Get](https://code.google.com/p/cyg-get/). You might see if either of those supports saving packages to a location and the using that location when restoring. Or you can always just zip up the cygwin folder. I often move cygwin to a new computer by just grabbing the whole folder from another system.

You also may be able to just use the command line options of the [cygwin setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli)

Comment: The Chocolatey package manager seems to install only msi-packages? The cyg-get plugin itself seems rather immature at the moment. Installing lists is supposed to be supported but is in fact not, and it is not possible to remove packages or download packages without installing.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, Cygwin packages are just tarballs. You can download them and untar them into your Cygwin root directory.

Comment: That's true, but it neglects the post-installation scripts and system-wide updates such as rebasing, that the setup program performs.  So the files would be there, but the packages might not be completely installed.

Comment: Understood. Having not used Cygwin all that much I'm not familiar with their installation package contrivances. It looks like your answer here seems like a reasonable solution to the OP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7366200/40764